# Retrieve data from a MySQL database to be presented in an iPad app

Tags: mysql, ios, xcode4

I have an application for iPad that needs to be able to connect to a MySQL database to populate a table with information. The database is already set up however I do not know how to make the application populate the table view with the data from the MySQL Server. Do the cells in the table view have to be dynamic or can they be static? Im pretty new to iOS development so any help would be appreciated. Im starting fresh with a project so lets assume that i am starting with a View Controller that has a button, when pressed, goes through a navigation controller to display the table view controller.

I understand that the application cannot connect directly to the MySQL (information gathered from posts on this website) so a PHP file has been generated that updates as the data on the MySQL server updates.

Thanks

Comment: Try this [tutorial](http://www.xappsoftware.com/wordpress/2012/06/11/using-ios-to-retrieve-data-from-a-remote-mysql-database/) on retrieving data from mysql db.

Answer (score 0):

I used the following tutorial to learn how to parse data from my xml files into tables. It needed minor tweaking for XCode 4.2, but simple to do. I use XML files hosted on our site that are populated from our SQL servers daily. If you need more specific guidance, I'll be glad to provide it.

http://www.lonhosford.com/lonblog/2011/05/11/xcode-4-iphone-mountains-of-the-usa-tutorial-lesson-1-setup-the-app/